# Stemming function in r

Tags: r, text, stemming

Package `corpus` provides a custom stemming function. The stemming function should, when given a term as an input, return the stem of the term as the output.

From [Stemming Words](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corpus/vignettes/stemmer.html) I taken the following example, that uses the `hunspell` dictionary to do the stemming.

First I define the sentences on which to test this function:

```
sentences<-c("The color blue neutralizes orange yellow reflections.", 
             "Zod stabbed me with blue Kryptonite.", 
             "Because blue is your favourite colour.",
             "Red is wrong, blue is right.",
             "You and I are going to yellowstone.",
             "Van Gogh looked for some yellow at sunset.",
             "You ruined my beautiful green dress.",
             "You do not agree.",
             "There's nothing wrong with green.")
```

The custom stemming function is:

```
stem_hunspell <- function(term) {
  # look up the term in the dictionary
  stems <- hunspell::hunspell_stem(term)[[1]]

  if (length(stems) == 0) { # if there are no stems, use the original term
    stem <- term
  } else { # if there are multiple stems, use the last one
    stem <- stems[[length(stems)]]
  }

  stem
}
```

This code

```
sentences=text_tokens(sentences, stemmer = stem_hunspell)
```

produces:

```
> sentences
[[1]]
[1] "the"        "color"      "blue"       "neutralize" "orange"     "yellow"    
[7] "reflection" "."         

[[2]]
[1] "zod"        "stabbed"    "me"         "with"       "blue"       "kryptonite"
[7] "."         

[[3]]
[1] "because"   "blue"      "i"         "your"      "favourite" "colour"   
[7] "."        

[[4]]
[1] "re"    "i"     "wrong" ","     "blue"  "i"     "right" "."    

[[5]]
[1] "you"         "and"         "i"           "are"         "go"         
[6] "to"          "yellowstone" "."          

[[6]]
[1] "van"    "gogh"   "look"   "for"    "some"   "yellow" "at"     "sunset" "."     

[[7]]
[1] "you"       "ruin"      "my"        "beautiful" "green"     "dress"    
[7] "."        

[[8]]
[1] "you"   "do"    "not"   "agree" "."    

[[9]]
[1] "there"   "nothing" "wrong"   "with"    "green"   "."
```

After stemming I would like to apply other operations on the text, e.g. removing stop words. Anyway, when I applied the `tm`-function:

```
removeWords(sentences,stopwords)
```

to my sentences, I obtained the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("removeWords", x) : 
 no applicable method for 'removeWords' applied to an object of class "list"
```

If I use

```
unlist(sentences)
```

I don't get the desired result, because I end up with a `chr` of 65 elements. The desired result should be (e.g. for the the first sentences):

```
"the color blue neutralize orange yellow reflection."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove stopwords from each `sentence`, you could use `lapply` :

```
library(tm)
lapply(sentences, removeWords, stopwords())

#[[1]]
#[1] ""           "color"      "blue"       "neutralize" "orange"     "yellow"     "reflection" "."         

#[[2]]
#[1] "zod"        "stabbed"    ""           ""           "blue"       "kryptonite" "."  
#...
#...
```

However, from your expected output it looks you want to paste the text together.

```
lapply(sentences, paste0, collapse = " ")

#[[1]]
#[1] "the color blue neutralize orange yellow reflection ."

#[[2]]
#[1] "zod stabbed me with blue kryptonite ."
#....
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `map`

```
library(tm)
library(purrr)
map(sentences, removeWords, stopwords())
#[[1]]
#[1] ""           "color"      "blue"       "neutralize" "orange"     "yellow"     "reflection"
#[8] "."         

#[[2]]
#[1] "zod"        "stabbed"    ""           ""           "blue"       "kryptonite" "."
```